# undefined method `paginate' kaminari-mongoid rails 5

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5, kaminari

Use monogid 6.0.0 and rails 5

this is my controller :

```
def index
    @images = Image.page(7).per(50).padding(3)
end
```

and view :

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= image.image %></td>
      <td><%= image.mime %></td>
      <td><%= image.user_id %></td>
      <td><%= image.product_ids %></td>
      <td><%= image.updated_at %></td>
      <td><%= image.created_at %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', image %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_image_path(image) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', image, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
   </tr>

<% end %>
<%= paginate @images %>
```

trace :

> actionview (5.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:159:in `block in
>   render' activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in`instrument' actionview
>   (5.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:354:in `instrument' actionview
>   (5.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in`render' actionview (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels)
>   in render_template' actionview (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:42:in`block in
>   instrument' activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
>   activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in
>   `instrument' actionview (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:41:in`instrument'
>   actionview (5.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in
>   `block in render_template' actionview (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in`
>   render_with_layout' actionview (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
>   actionview (5.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in`
>   render' actionview (5.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in
>   `render_template' actionview (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in`render' actionview (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template' actionpack
>   (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in`
>   _render_template' actionview (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in`render_to_body'
>   actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in
>   `render_to_body' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:26:in`render' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render' actionpack
>   (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in`block (2
>   levels) in render' activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
>   /home/draf/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in`
>   realtime' activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in`block in render'
>   actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in
>   `cleanup_view_runtime' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in`render'
>   actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:36:in `default_render'
>   actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in`block in
>   send_action' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `tap'
>   actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in`
>   send_action' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action' actionpack
>   (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in`
>   process_action' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
>   activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in`call'
>   activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2
>   levels) in compile' activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in`call' activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
>   activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in`
>   _run_process_action_callbacks' activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks' actionpack
>   (5.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in
>   `process_action' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in`block in
>   process_action' activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
>   activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in
>   `instrument' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
>   actionpack (5.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in`process'
>   actionview (5.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
>   actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
>   actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in`
>   dispatch' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve' actionpack
>   (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in`block in serve'
>   actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
>   actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in`serve'
>   actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in
>   `call' rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in`call' rack (2.0.1)
>   lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call' rack (2.0.1)
>   lib/rack/head.rb:12:in`call' rack (2.0.1)
>   lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context' rack (2.0.1)
>   lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in`call' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call' actionpack
>   (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in`block in
>   call' activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in
>   `__run_callbacks__' activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in`_run_call_callbacks'
>   activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in
>   `run_callbacks' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in`call' actionpack
>   (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
>   actionpack (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in`
>   call' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
>   web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in`call_app'
>   web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in
>   call' web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in`catch'
>   web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
>   actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in`call'
>   railties (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app' railties
>   (5.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`block in call' activesupport
>   (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
>   activesupport (5.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`
>   tagged' activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged' railties (5.0.1)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`call' sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
>   lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in`call' rack (2.0.1)
>   lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call' rack (2.0.1)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in`call' activesupport (5.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in
>   `call' actionpack (5.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in`call' actionpack
>   (5.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call' rack
>   (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in`call' railties (5.0.1)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call' puma (3.7.0)
>   lib/puma/configuration.rb:226:in`call' puma (3.7.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request' puma (3.7.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:415:in`process_client' puma (3.7.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run' puma (3.7.0)
>   lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in`block in spawn_thread'

Comment: Could you list the related gems you have added into Gemfile?